# How To Remove System Directory Does Not Exist

Tags: .htaccess, kohana

I Am Trying To Install A Kohana Based Script But I Am Getting A Error See Above In The Image

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxMDu.png)

And I Could Not Find What To Do But I Am Sue it Is Related To .Htaccess

```
  SetEnv KOHANA_ENV development

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>


# Disable directory listing
Options -Indexes 


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>


# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
# RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
RewriteRule .* index.php [PT]

# Remove trailing slash
# RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]
# RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value magic_quotes_gpc                0
  php_value register_globals                0
  php_value session.auto_start              0
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_value mbstring.encoding_translation   0
</IfModule>
```

according to script owner they said do step 3
 Run the installer

Open .htaccess and make the following changes:

Set the correct RewriteBase

but i do not know what to write and what to edit in it i need a little bit help over it

Comment: your screen shows disc error, not wrong web configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that the `application`, `modules` and `system` folders are not in the same directory as `index.php`. If you've moved /renamed them you need to change their location in `index.php`.

If you deleted/modified something by accident, try download Kohana again, obviously the error has nothing to do with .htaccess.
For more info, read the docs https://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/install